# Display data collected from MYSQL to html page using AngularJs and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. I am working on an project where the application displays content from MYSQL(dummy table with flight details which has Airlines,departure,Arrival,Duration and Price columns) in a HTML table using PHP and AngualarJS. I have written the code for AngularJs and PHP. Now,when I try to display the retrieved data to html I am not able to do so(I tried to access my PHP file directly, and it displays the data in JSON formate ).Please look at my HTML(flights.html),JAVASCRIPT/AngularJS(Flights.js) and PHP(Flights.php) code:

### **HTML CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mymodule">
<head>
<title>Flights</title>        
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="Flights.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Airlines</th>                     
         <th>Departure</th> 
         <th>Arrival</th>
         <th>Duration</th>
         <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat = "flights in response">
            <td>{{flights.Airlines}}</td>                                        
            <td>{{flights.departure}}</td>
            <td>{{flights.Arrival}}</td>
            <td>{{flights.Duration}}</td>
            <td>{{flights.Price}}</td>                       
          </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>       
</body>
</html>
```

### **JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
var response;
var app = angular.module('mymodule', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) 
{  $http.get("Flights.php")
   .success(function(response)
   {
       //$scope.myWelcome = response;
       //$scope.myWelcome = response.data;       
       $scope.response = response.data;
       console.log(response);      
   })
   .error(function()
   {
        $scope.response = "error in fetching data";
   });
});
```

### **PHP CODE**

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","","",'flight_details');
$data = array();
// Check connection
if (!$conn)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else
{      
    $sql = "select * from flights";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0)
    {

        while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
        {

            $data[] = $row;

        }
        $res_final = json_encode($data);         
        echo $res_final;
    } 
    else
    {
        echo"0 results";

    }   
    $conn->close();
}
?>
```

moreover when I see the console I can find the objects(array elements) as Array[6]0: Object1: Object2: Object3: Object4: Object5: Objectlength: 6__proto__: Array[0]
By this I am aware that data has been passed to javascript but by Angularjs code/javascript code is not appropriate.
So, please help me with this, and thanks in advance

Comment: can you post what is there in the json

Comment: show us what the actual properties are in a json object. Note that javascript is case sensitive. You have some properties in view with capital letter and some without which seems strange

Comment: @Sajeetharan 
Array[6]
0
:
Object
0
:
"Indian Airlines"
1
:
"2016-05-20"
2
:
"2016-05-21"
3
:
"25"
4
:
"1546"
Airlines
:
"Indian Airlines"
Arrival
:
"2016-05-21"
Duration
:
"25"
Price
:
"1546"
departure
:
"2016-05-20"
__proto__:Object1:Object2:Object3:Object4:Object5:Objectlength:6__proto__
:
Array[0] This is what I get in the console

Comment: @Sajeetharan Sorry, not possible

Comment: can you create a plunker ?

Comment: Try:  $scope.response = response; not " $scope.response = response.data;"

Comment: @LuizEduardodeChristo: Thanks for the help, I did use $scope.response = response; instead of $scope.response = response.data; any way if you do not mind can you explain why my code hasn't  worked earlier, please. It might help any one in future. Once again thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
$scope.response = response;
```

instead of:

```
$scope.response = response.data;
```

Here's why:

if you use the promise:

```
.then(function successCallback(response)
```

then you should do `response.data`;

As you are using `.success`, the first argument already is your `response.data`.
In this case you called it 'response' and this may have confused you. When using .success avoid naming the argument as 'reponse'. Use something like:

```
 .success(function(data) {           
      $scope.lstWeeklyMenu = data;
```

Take a look at: http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/25/dont-use-$https-success/

and

https://www.peterbe.com/plog/promises-with-$http

In short:

The `.then(response)` you get the response object:

The response object has these properties:

- data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
- status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
- headers – {function([headerName])} Header getter function.
- config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
- statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

and using `.success()` each one of the response properties is an argument:

.success(data, status)