# $http.get() .then() vs success()

Tags: angularjs

In this link: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_tables_index

```
$http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
});
```

1. Why I change `.then()` to `success()` cannot work? Because I see `success(function(){})` works before.
2. Why I cannot change 'response' to 'data', then `$scope.names = data`?

Comment: Why would you want to change and use success()? success() is deprecated for a long time, and doesn't even exist anymore in 1.6. Have you read the documentation of $http? Because it answers your question.

Comment: ... and the signature of the `then` callback is different than the signature of the `success` callback. The `response.data` of the `then` callback is equivalent to the `data` (first) parameter of the `success` callback

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40638771/6361565

Comment: Can anybody use success() in that example to make it work?

Comment: I think that success might return differently than then. It might actually return the `data` property. But, as others have said, the `success` and `failure` callbacks have been deprecated in favor of `then` (without a second argument for success) and `catch` for error conditions.